# Url query string , mean stack

Tags: parameters, stack, angular5, mean, query-string

I have an application with mean stack, How could I make my url like this?

skill/1?role=123&role=456

**service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { GLOBAL } from '../global.service';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfesionalService {
  public url: string;

constructor(private _http: HttpClient){
    this.url = GLOBAL.url;
  }
getProfe(token, role):Observable<any>{

   let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
               .set('Authorization',token);

  return this._http.get(this.url+'ads/professsional/1?role='  + role,  
{headers: headers});
 }
 }
```

**Component**

```
getPro(){
this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
  let role = params['role'];

this._professionalservice.getProfe(this.token,role).subscribe(
    response => {console.log(response.professionals)
        if(!response.professionals){
            this._router.navigate(['/']);
        }else{
           this.professionals=response.professionals;

        }

    },
    error => {
        var errorMessage = <any>error;
        console.log(errorMessage);
        if(errorMessage != null){
            this.status = 'error';
        }
    }
);}  
);
}
```

**routing**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'skill/:role', component: SkillComponent},
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

it is only valid for the url

skill/1?role=123

Could someone help me or tell me where I could find information?

Comment: The url that you are building in `get` request is for backend and the routing you are showing is applicable within angular. Can you be more clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: **my backend url would be this **                                                                    
    `ads/professsional/1?role=123&role=456&role=585` 
role I can put it so many times @AmitChigadani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this below code is helpful for you. What I understood is, you want to add same `queryParam` multiple times dynamically for backend url.

And I assume you are passing `roles` parameter as array containing `[123,456,789]`

```
getProfe(token, roles : Array<number>):Observable<any>{
   let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
               .set('Authorization',token);

    let url = this.url+'ads/professsional/1';

    if(roles.length > 0) {
        url += '?';  // concat '?'
        roles.forEach((r) => 
          {
              url += 'role=' + r + '&';         // add multiple params like role='123'
          }
        )
        url.splice(url.length-1, 1); // remove trailing &
    }   

  return this._http.get(url, {headers: headers});
}
```

Comment: I have tried and this happens                                                                     **Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Comment: Add type `Array<number>` to `roles` param as shown in the edited answer. I also said you should be passing array of roles to `getProfe('fdfds', [123,456])`